# Search iTunes for podcast by title

Tags: ios, json, api, search, itunes

I'd like to find the specific podcast episode titled "#1: The Single White Guy Focus Group."  According to the [iTunes search API](https://affiliate.itunes.apple.com/resources/documentation/itunes-store-web-service-search-api/#searching), I believe I should be able to find it with the following:

> https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=%231:+The+Single+Straight+Guy+Focus+Group&entity=podcast&attribute=keywordsTerm

But that returns an empty JSON.  I also tried

> https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=The+Single+Straight+Guy+Focus+Group&entity=podcast

... and ...

> https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=The+Single+Straight+Guy+Focus+Group

... but I always get the same result.

```
{
 "resultCount":0,
 "results": []
}
```

I'm baffled.  I know the episode is in there - here it is.

https://itunes.apple.com/us/podcast/1-single-straight-guy-focus/id775053292?i=1000375469754&mt=2

(posting full url so deliberately, so you can see that indeed there is a url which does point to that specific episode)

So why can't I find it?

EDIT: Note that I am doing this in an Obj-C iOS app, in case that is relevant.

Comment: Hey Max, did you find a resolution to this? I too ran into the same problem

Comment: Not yet.  I've written some very hack-y code with url formatting to try and brute force the answer but it is not good at all yet.  Thanks!  I'll post an answer if/when I find one.  @jonmecer

Comment: Have you found any solution?

Comment: @MateuszKaflowski no.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After a TON of hair-pulling, I've found that there is an undocumented entity (podcastEpisode) that does what we all want.

So, on the off-chance the original poster is still at this after 3 years (or more likely other frustrated folks like myself browsing) - try this (using the original example):

```
https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=The+Single+Straight+Guy+Focus+Group&entity=podcastEpisode
```

Comment: welcome to SO and thank you for solving this long-abandoned problem!

Comment: This api seems to be broken (last 48h at least). The same happens for episodes lookup like `https://itunes.apple.com/lookup?entity=podcastEpisode&id=xxxxxxx`

Comment: @loretoparisi just found this out myself...sigh. Hopefully temporary and/or a blip before an improved episode API release? (fingers crossed pessimistically, lol)

Comment: interesting fact here `https://affiliate.itunes.apple.com/resources/documentation/itunes-store-web-service-search-api/` the doc reports `podcast-episode` as entity, but it does not work either. Maybe it's a typo.

Comment: It's working again! AND they added the ability to grab all episodes for a podcast using lookup by podcast (collectionId)!!

Like so: https://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id=1251196416&country=US&media=podcast&entity=podcastEpisode&limit=100

I'm shocked but happy! :D

Comment: Works for me, you're a hero!

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately apple API searches only by the title of the podcast and not by the title of the episode. I'm trying to add a search by episode on my app but to no avail so far

Comment: Thanks @Izbonzo!  Do you have evidence to this effect, such as Apple docs stating as much?

Answer (score 1):

I came here with a slightly different problem, and also found the documentation for the itunes search to be a bit lacking.  But thanks to @ntschier I was able to put this search together:

https://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id=1469663053&country=US&media=podcast&entity=podcastEpisode&limit=5

This gives me the five most recent episodes from my podcast.  I will be using this with Zapier (hopefully) to follow my podcast and automatically tweet/FB/LinkedIn out new episodes using their Webhooks feature.

The only problem I'm having is there seems to be a delay between the time something shows up on Apple Podcasts and when it shows up in an itunes search.  Not sure what's up with that.  By delay, I mean many hours at least.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer Curtis.  I suspect Apple has some logic to go through a ton of RSS feeds and update their internal database on some repeating schedule.  It would not surprise me if this takes a few hours to run, hence the delay you perceive.

Comment: Given that they control both platforms, I'm not sure I follow that.  I can see why there would be a delay between me publishing my podcast and Apple Podcasts following its RSS Feed and then creating the Apple Podcasts page for that episode.  What I don't understand is why they don't then automatically tell itunes to update its listing w/the episode.  itunes isn't following the RSS feeds; it's just doing what Apple Podcasts tells it to do.  It's also annoying that the delay is extremely inconsistent, from a few minutes to several hours.  I just find that strange.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34004677)

Comment: Apple support confirmed this is the expected behavior. :)